# error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token //(struct)

Tags: c++, struct

I need to make a program that gets a fraction from the user and then simplifies it.

I know how to do it and have done most of the code but I keep getting this error "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token".

I have declared a struct called ReducedForm which holds the simplified numerator and denominator, now what Im trying to do is send the simplified values to this struct.
Here is my code;

In Rational.h;

```
#ifndef RATIONAL_H
#define RATIONAL_H

using namespace std;

struct ReducedForm
{
    int iSimplifiedNumerator;
    int iSimplifiedDenominator;
};

//I have a class here for the other stuff in the program
#endif
```

In Rational.cpp;

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "rational.h" 
using namespace std;

void Rational :: SetToReducedForm(int iNumerator, int iDenominator)
{
int iGreatCommDivisor = 0;

iGreatCommDivisor = GCD(iNumerator, iDenominator);

//The next 2 lines is where i get the error
ReducedForm.iSimplifiedNumerator = iNumerator/iGreatCommDivisor;
ReducedForm.iSimplifiedDenominator = iDenominator/iGreatCommDivisor;
};
```

Comment: 'using namespace' in a header file is not a kind thing to do to users of your file.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to access the struct statically with a `.` instead of `::`, nor are its members `static`. Either instantiate `ReducedForm`:

```
ReducedForm rf;
rf.iSimplifiedNumerator = 5;
```

or change the members to `static` like this:

```
struct ReducedForm
{
    static int iSimplifiedNumerator;
    static int iSimplifiedDenominator;
};
```

In the latter case, you must access the members with `::` instead of `.` I highly doubt however that the latter is what you are going for ;)

Answer (score 5):

The struct's name is `ReducedForm`; you need to make an *object* (instance of the `struct` or `class`) and use that. Do this:

```
ReducedForm MyReducedForm;
MyReducedForm.iSimplifiedNumerator = iNumerator/iGreatCommDivisor;
MyReducedForm.iSimplifiedDenominator = iDenominator/iGreatCommDivisor;
```

Answer (score 3):

`ReducedForm` is a type, so you cannot say

```
ReducedForm.iSimplifiedNumerator = iNumerator/iGreatCommDivisor;
```

You can only use the `.` operator on an instance:

```
ReducedForm rf;
rf.iSimplifiedNumerator = iNumerator/iGreatCommDivisor;
```

Comment: oh yes, I see that now. I don't know how i missed that. Silly mistake. Thank you