# Expected unqualified-id before '.' token

Tags: vector, dev-c++

I'm pretty new at c++ so talk caveman to me. I'm trying to get the code to run in a loop and and when the loop is done calculate the total and everything ordered. I'm running into this error and I'm not sure why.

[Error] expected unqualified-id before '.' token

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string again;
char pType, pSize, topping, temp;
const int SMALL = 1;
int type = 0, size = 0;
const int MEDIUM = 2;
const int LARGE = 3;
const int DEEPDISH = 1;
const int HANDTOSSED = 2;
const int PAN = 3;
double total = 0;

class Pizza
{
    private:
          int type;
          int size;
          bool cheese;    
          bool pepperoni; 

    public:
          Pizza();
          int getType();
          int getSize();
          bool getCheese();
          bool getPepperoni();
          void setType(int t);
          void setSize(int s);
          void setCheese(bool choice);
          void setPepperoni(bool choice);

  void outputDescription();
  double computePrice();
};

class Order
{
private:
    vector<Pizza> c; 

public:
    Order();
    void customerOrder();
    void customerTotal();
    void customerinput();
};

Pizza::Pizza()
{
  type = DEEPDISH;
  size = SMALL;
  cheese = pepperoni = false;
}

int Pizza::getType()
{
  return type;
}

int Pizza::getSize()
{
  return size;
}

bool Pizza::getCheese()
{
  return cheese;
}

bool Pizza::getPepperoni()
{
  return pepperoni;
}

void Pizza::setType(int t)
{
  type = t;
}

void Pizza::setSize(int s)
{
  size = s;
}

void Pizza::setCheese(bool choice)
{
  cheese = choice;
}

void Pizza::setPepperoni(bool choice)
{
  pepperoni= choice;
}

void Pizza::outputDescription()
{
  switch (size)
  {
      case SMALL:
        cout << "Small "; break;
      case MEDIUM:
        cout << "Medium "; break;
      case LARGE:
        cout << "Large "; break;
      default:
        cout << "Unknown" ;
  }

  switch (type)
  {
      case DEEPDISH:
        cout << "deepdish "; break;
      case HANDTOSSED:
        cout << "hand tossed "; break;
      case PAN:
        cout << "pan "; break;
      default:
        cout << "Unknown";
  }

  cout << "pizza";
}

double Pizza::computePrice()
{
  double cost = 0.0;
  switch (size)
  {
  case SMALL:
    cost += 10; break;
  case MEDIUM:
    cost += 14; break;
  case LARGE:
    cost += 17; break;
  }

  if (cheese)
    cost += 2.0;
  if (pepperoni)
    cost += 2.0;

  return cost;
}

Order custmizedTotal;
Pizza myPizza;  
bool done=false;
void Order::customerinput(){
while ( again == "y"){  
        cout << "What sized pizza, please enter S, M OR L: ";
        cin >> pSize;
        cin.clear();

        switch(pSize)
        {
            case 'S': case 's':
            size = SMALL; break;
            case 'M': case 'm':
            size = MEDIUM; break;
            case 'L': case 'l':
            size = LARGE; break;
        }

        cout << "What type of pizza, enter D for Deepdish, H for Hand tossed, and P for Pan: ";
        cin >> pType;
        cin.clear();

        switch(pType)
        {
            case 'D': case 'd':
            type = DEEPDISH; break;
            case 'H': case 'h':
            type = HANDTOSSED; break;
            case 'P': case 'p':
            type = PAN; break;
        }


        myPizza.setSize(size);
        myPizza.setType(type);

        cout << "Would you like cheese (y/n)? ";
        cin >> topping;
        cin.clear();

        if (topping == 'Y' || topping == 'y')
            myPizza.setCheese(true);

        cout << "Would you like pepperoni (y/n)? ";
        cin >> topping;
        cin.clear();

        if (topping == 'Y' || topping == 'y')
            myPizza.setPepperoni(true);


      cout << endl
       << "Your order: ";
      myPizza.outputDescription();
      cout << endl;
      cout << "Price: $" << myPizza.computePrice() << endl;

      cout << "Again? (y/n)";
      cin >> again;


    }
}

void Order::customerTotal(){

    cout << "Your Total order is: " << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<c.size(); i++)
    { 
        c[i].outputDescription();
        cout << endl;
        cout << c[i].computePrice();
        cout << endl;
        total=total+c[i].computePrice();
    }       
    cout << "Totat Cost: $" << total;
    cout << endl;
    c.push_back(myPizza);
}

int main()
{   
    custmizedTotal.customerinput();
    //Order.customerinput(); 
    if(again != "y"){
        custmizedTotal.customerTotal();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token //(struct)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062616/error-expected-unqualified-id-before-token-struct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
int main(){
    Order.customerinput(); //error is here
    if(again != "y"){
        custmizedTotal.customerTotal(); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

By:

```
int main(){
    custmizedTotal.customerinput(); // Change this line
    if(again != "y"){
        custmizedTotal.customerTotal(); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The second error that you have as caused because you forgot to define Order constructor.

Add this to your code (above main() method):

```
Order::Order(){
    // Set the initial values for order
}
```

You also forgot to add customerOrder method (but this does not cause error since you are not using this method):

```
void Order::customerOrder() {
}
```

Comment: As in 'int main()
{ custmizedTotal.customerTotal(); }
 return 0;
}

Comment: I applied the change and I received the error. [Error] ld returned 1 exit status. With the message: undefined reference to `Order::Order()'

Comment: Please, share your whole code... It is hard to see what you already done and what you are missing

Comment: Okay it runs now. But it's not asking for input from the user.

Comment: Ok. Initial problem was solved. You were having trouble to build and now it is fixed... Now, you should play with your application. Further problems, raise new questions.  Kindly request to accept the answer since this question was answered.